# pysimplegui prevent button color change and text animation on click

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Is there a way to prevent button click animation and color changing on button click with pysimplegui?  I am after a material design look button that can be clicked but doesn't change.  The following is the code for a button but when it is clicked, the color changes and the text animates on click, both of which I would like to prevent:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

variableText = "topline"
variableNum = 12345
layout = [

    [sg.Button('\n'.join([variableText, str(variableNum)]),size = (8,2), button_color=("#FFFFFF","#9945B5"),font=('Arial', 8),border_width=0,bind_return_key=True, key='-BUTTON-')],

]

window = sg.Window("Button Color Example", layout, finalize=True)



while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add following statement after window finalized to block all default actions by tkinter.

```py
window['-BUTTON-'].bind("<Button-1>", "", propagate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the color change by updating the color accordingly in the event handler:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

variableText = "topline"
variableNum = 12345
button_color = ("#FFFFFF", "#9945B5")
layout = [
    [
        sg.Button(
            "\n".join([variableText, str(variableNum)]),
            size=(8, 2),
            button_color=button_color,  # sg.TRANSPARENT_BUTTON
            font=("Arial", 8),
            border_width=0,
            bind_return_key=True,
            key="-BUTTON-",
        )
    ],
]

window = sg.Window("Button Color Example", layout, finalize=True)
# without this initial update, the first click will still change the color
window["-BUTTON-"].update(button_color=button_color)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "-BUTTON-":
        window["-BUTTON-"].update(button_color=button_color)
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "Exit"):
        break

window.close()
```

As for the button animation, this cannot be achieved easily, as it seems to be deeply connected with the QPushbutton, see e.g. [this thread](https://python-forum.io/thread-17718.html) were a potential workaround with a clickable label is suggested instead.

Oddly enough, this [missing animation seems to have been a bug 4 years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/PySimpleGUI/comments/e5e7tt/pysimpleguiqt_button_animation_on_press/), so maybe you can dig out the fix which enabled the animation and disable it again ;)

Comment: Oh this is so close to what I am looking for, I'm looking into preventing the animation also but so far haven't found how to disable it.